# Is there a way to change aspect ratio when playing videos in Videos (Audience) player?

Tags: videos, audience

Some videos start with an improper aspect ratio. Is there a way (shortcut?) to cycle aspect ratio?

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted, it seems a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5):

`vlc` allows you to cycle between different aspect ratios using the `a` key or the menu `Video->Aspect Ratio`

---

`mpv` allows to cycle between different aspect ratios with a key set in `~/.mpv/input.conf`. To use the `A` key, you need to have the line `A cycle-values video-aspect "16:9" "4:3" "2.35:1" "-1"`. The file (and folder) can (and may need to) be created manually at that location, copy it from [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/input.conf): just uncomment that line (delete `#` in front), or set another key combination, like `a` or `Alt-a`.

Comment: sorry that I used the improper tag: I meant  the default eOS player Audience/Videos

Comment: considering VLC: the key for cycling aspect ratio is `a` (not `v` - albeit that is editable under Tools-Preferences-Hotkeys)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, at the risk of being considered rude, I need to ask why coderMess decided to not answer the user's question, but instead offer up advice on using another piece of software.

Sure, you can use VLC, but what if you don't want to?

And why bother answering a question with the advice of using different software?

If we want this whole thing to work, we have to let the developers know about these bugs, not just tell someone to use something else.

Comment: True, but you should post this as a comment under the answer you are referring to and not as a different answer. In fact the user codeMess whom you are addressing may not even be announced that you posted this answer, while a comment will surely be referred to that user. (only the author of a question gets announcements on everything thereunder). - Also, please consider that if an answer on a different player may be inadequate, another answer on that being inadequate is also inadequate... :)

Comment: Indeed, I didn't get notice of the answer. The reason is that back when I answered, the question did not specify which player it was (it can be read in the comments to my answer). I agree with you posture, though.